# How to use "This.props" inside newly Create element in video.js in react

Tags: reactjs, video.js

```
 let flag =  true;
        const NextId = this.props.nextVideo && this.props.nextVideo.get("_id");
        console.log("Yahsvi",NextId)
        var Button = videojs.getComponent('Button');
        var MyButton = videojs.extend(Button, {
            constructor: function () {
                Button.apply(this, arguments);
                this.addClass('fa');
                this.addClass('fa-angle-right');
            },
            handleClick: function () {

                 navigate(`/videos/${NextId && NextId }`);
            }
        });
```

I have value in NextID, But when I used it inside handleClick I am getting null,
How can I access nextID inside handleClick,

Help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that this statement ```NextId && NextId``` works as intended? Shouldn't it just be ```navigate(`/videos/${NextId}`);```?

Comment: yes, its working. 
I am getting ID under NextId "127y4jkdnf84343fg",
But under HandleClick i am getting null,
But if i normally console i am getting null
@Gh05d

Comment: Please, help if there is any another way to do it @Gh05d

Comment: Please show your component and/or how you used the MyButton

Comment: Ok, so the first console.log Yahsvi displays the id. Correct? But if you make the same console.log in the handleClick function it is null? Where is <MyButton /> used?

Comment: I fixed this issue. Thanks